# javascript object literal and jquery each

Tags: javascript, jquery, each, literals

I am trying to start learning OO JS and have one quick question (i have condensed my actual issue for ease).

Basically, the following alert just returns [Object object], i want it to return 3 different alert boxes

```
<body>

    <div id="bob">
        <div>f</div>
        <div>t</div>
        <div>q</div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var Person = {
            name: $('#bob div').each(
                function(){
                    $(this).text();
                }
            )                   
        }
        alert(Person.name);

    });
    </script>

</body>
```

Any guidance much appreciated.

Adi.

Comment: Your code will assign the return value of `$('#bob div').each(...)` to `Person.name`, which is a jQuery object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can do something like this:

```
var Person = {
    alertNames: function() {
        $('#bob div').each(
            function(){
                alert($(this).text());
            }
        );
    };
}
Person.alertNames();
```

Note, though, that in JavaScript names that start with a capital (in this case, `Person`) are usually reserved for **constructor functions** (i.e. functions that are used to create new instances using the `new` keyword). These are usually called **types**, because the name **classes** would be misleading.

If you want to make your code truly Object Oriented, you could try something like this:

```
var Person = function(name) {
    var container = $('#' + name);

    this.alertNames: function() {
        $('div', container).each(
            function(){
                alert($(this).text());
            }
        );
    };
}
var bob = new Person('bob');
bob.alertNames();
```

Recommended reading:

- [Professional JavaScript for Web Developers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/047022780X) (book)
- [Object Oriented Programming in JavaScript](http://mckoss.com/jscript/object.htm) (article)

Answer (score 0):

In javascript `alert` boxes is not something that you return. It is something that you call and which pops up an alert. So if you want 3 alerts you need to call the `alert` function 3 times. Currently you are calling it only once.

I suspect that what you are trying is to concatenate the results of the selector. In this case use `.map` instead of `.each`:

```
var Person = {
    name: $('#bob div').map(function() {
        return $(this).text();
    }).get().join(',')                  
};
alert(Person.name);
```

Another possibility is to put the alert inside the `.each` callback.

Comment: If you want to concatenate the content, you also have to add `.get().join()`.

Comment: @FelixKling, good point. Answer updated to take into account.